# Transferring array to another Worksheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

In one worksheet called 'Flange Management Sheet' I have quite a large data base of information and in another Sheet Called 'Cert Sheet' I have a Form I've created with fields that need to be filled from the FMS.

I would like to select the first cell in a row of information and click the button and the cert sheet is populated.

I think the way to go about this is using an Array.

I've created this

```
Array(“A = Q14”, “B = C12”, “D = Q12”, “K = C11”, “L=C14”, “M=C16”, “N=C17”, “O = C19”, “P = Q19”, “Q=C18”, “T=C27”, “U=Q27”, “X = C24”, “Y = C25”, “Z=Q24”, “AA=Q25”, “AB=Q26”, “AD = L5", “AE = N30”)
```

Its what to do with it and how to implement it in VBA.

This has all come about because currently you have to enter all the information manually in a Word document and there must be a simple way of auto populating.

EDIT For Clarity - 
What I'm looking for is using the information on the Flange Management Matrix to be used to populate a form I created on a separate worksheet.

In the FMM Sheet I have A - AO of fields with about 400 rows of relevant information under those fields.
So for Example in Column A - 'Tag ID, Column B - 'Line No', Column K - 'Drawing Number' Etc...  Followed by 400 rows Unique Tag ID's, and so on along the columns.

I have created a form in another Worksheet called 'Cert sheet' its just a printable version of certain relevant to client information in the information collected on the FMM for the client.

What I would like is (for example) click on Cell A10 or any Cell in column A (the Tag ID field), Click 'Make Cert' and then use the fields from the FMM relevent and populate the Cert Sheet.

Again for example using the 'Tag ID' Field. Cell A10 will need to be placed in to Cell Q14 on the Cert Sheet.
What I've done above with the Array is Column on FMM = Relevent Cell on Cert Sheet.

Comment: please avoid providing external resource as part of your question's content.. since it might be a broken link sometimes and ruin the question.. and you can also describe your table using characters in this very post.. It takes more effort indeed, but please do so..

Comment: Agree with @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 at this point let's forget about that other website and do a better job explaining the structure of your own worksheet, and exactly what you're trying to accomplish.   Read through your Q again and explain what you mean by "Boom Cert sheet is populated" (with what? from where? what is the relationship between the selected cell and the data that's populating the row, etc.)  Include examples of your data, descriptions of your sheet setup, etc.

Comment: Hi, Sorry about the link, ive now edited the origional post to try and explain a little better.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier - instead of using an array - to create a "config" sheet in your workbook and read the mapping from there.

Say (e.g.) you put your mapping data in A2:B10, where ColA has the source column letter and ColB has the destination cell on the form you want to fill.

```
Sub Transfer()
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet, rngConfig As Range
    Dim rwSrc As Range, rwMap As Range

    Set shtSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Flange Management Sheet")
    Set shtDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cert Sheet")
    Set rngConfig = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Config").Range("A2:B10")

    'exit if a range is not selected...
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    '...or if it's on the wrong sheet
    If Selection.Parent.Name <> shtSrc.Name Then Exit Sub

    'what row is selected?
    Set rwSrc = Selection.Cells(1).EntireRow

    'loop through each row in your config table
    For Each rwMap In rngConfig.Rows

         'make sure this row has a mapping
         If Len(rwMap.Cells(1).Value) > 0 And _
           Len(rwMap.Cells(2).Value) > 0 Then

           'transfer the value
           shtDest.Range(rwMap.Cells(2).Value) = _
                    rwSrc.Cells(1, rwMap.Cells(1).Value).Value

        End If
    Next rwMap

End Sub
```